# Manipular arquivos do cmd usando python

Tags: python, cmd

Olá!

Preciso criar um aplicativo em python para diminuir a mão de obra onde trabalho, utilizamos arquivos .bat para executar diversos comandos no cmd, porém alguns desses comandos manipulam IP's e como se trata de uma rede muito grande perdemos muito tempo alterando os IP's manualmente dentro de um arquivo de texto e criando outro .bat. Existe alguma forma, de manipular esses comandos do cmd utilizando Python ou outra linguagem?

Comment: Em python existe a lib `subprocess` com ela você por realizar operações no cmd. Segue [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) da documentação dela

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, em Python seria tranquilo criar um programa para gerenciar outros scripts .bat, e cria-los e descria-los de acordo com o IP.

Mas seria ainda mais fácil, e mais mantível, trocar de uma vez os vários conjuntos de ,bat que vocês tem lá por um único script Python que gerencie tudo --

.bat é uma forma encontrada de executar comandos do antigo DOS em lote - não chega nem a ser uma lingugem de shell, e tem que se fazer alguns contorcionismos para coisas tão triviais em "linguagens reais" como um if ou um for.

Para gerenciar scripts externos, você pode usar a biblioteca de frameworks - jinja2 - ela é a linguagem de templates padrão do Flask,e  talvez de outros frameworks Web. Mas a ideia de uma linguagem de templates é justamente ler um arquivo "base", e substituir marcações bem definidas da linguagem por variáveis controladas a partir do Python. Nesse caso, em vez de preencher os dados de uma página em HTML para servir na Web, vocês usariam o Jinja para preencher os IPs em um template de .bat,e  gravar em disco o arquivo resultante.

A documentação do Jinja está aqui: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/

Agora, na linha que as outras respostas apontam, pode ser muito mais prático usar Python de uma vez em vez dos .bat

Com o framework para aplicações de linha de comando `click` fica fácil criar automaticamente comandos no cmd que disparam ações em funções de um programa em Python, já com todos os parâmetros e arguemntos preechidos, e um sistema de ajuda impresso no terminal gerado automaticamente.

E existe toda uma família de formas para, de dentro do programa em Python, chamar comandos externos como se faz de um arquivo .bat, *caso* esses comandos façam coisas que tomem um pouco mais de tempo de fazer em Pythn (comandos de configuração específica de rede, por exemplo) - mas se forem comandos do tipo copiar arquivos, manipular dados em texto, etc..é mais simples fazer tudo em Python mesmo.

A documentação do click: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

E pr fim, para chamar outros comandos, pode se usar desde `os.system` - e você pode encurtar a chamada pra não precisar escrever demais:

```
from os import system as S

S("ipconfig")
```

Quando, se realmente for um projeto crítico, usar o módulo `suproccess` e suas várias funções para ter controle dos dados gerados por cada processo externo, código de saída, poder chamar comandos externos em paralelo, etc.

Documentação do subprocess: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 2):

Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow ( apesar de eu ser iniciante aqui também kkk ). Para a linguagem `Python`, existem dois módulos que podem lhe ajudar, chamados `os` e `subprocess`.

```
import os
command = "<insira o comando>"
if os.system(command) == 0: #Esta função retorna 0 caso deu tudo certo e 1 se deu erro
    print("Executado com sucesso.")
else:
    print("Erro ao executar o comando.")
```

Recomendo que você use o módulo `os` pois é bem mais simples de se trabalhar, mas caso você queira algo mais avançado ou queira obter um output, você pode usar o `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess
command = "<insira o comando>"
print(subprocess.getoutput(command))
```

Aqui em baixo eu vou deixar um exemplo bem legal:

```
import subprocess

while True:
    server = "www.google.com"
    output = subprocess.getoutput("ping "+server)
    for line in output.split("\n")[2:6]:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Haha valeu! Vou testar aqui, vamos ver o que vai sair. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Henrique bem vindo ao Stackoverflow, você pode escrever comandos shell utilizando o python de forma bem simples, como você não especificou exatamente o que precisa vou te passar uma forma genérica de fazer isso.

```
import os

os.system('dir')
os.system('ipconfig')
os.system('mkdir teste')
```

Dessa forma os comandos serão executados exatamente da mesma maneira que seriam executados no shell. Basta substituir a string pelo comando que você precisa executar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!